# What character encoding is this?

Tags: javascript

```
%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8C
```

Comment: OK. Gonzalo got it.  Why did you want to know?

Answer (score 19):

That is URL-encoded Russian. It says (translated from Cyrillic): [Sovetskaya Gavan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sovetskaya_Gavan) which means, literally, *Soviet Harbor*.

**Update:** steps I followed:

1. Used this URL [encoder/decoder](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/)
2. Used [Google translate](http://translate.google.com/) (I chose automatic detection of 'from' language, but I knew it was Russian)
3. Google search pointed to a city in Russia and its Wikipedia entry.

Comment: how'd you figure that out? :D

Comment: I updated my answer to explain the 2 steps.

Comment: Lol, +1 for speed and accuracy.

Comment: +1. Daaang! [I am not worthy bow]

Answer (score 2):

URL encoding. And then some other character encoding underneath, possibly UTF-8. URLDecode it and see what you see.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like [URI escaping](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt).  Each set of two hex digits after a % is the [ordinal](http://www.google.com/search?q=ascii+table) of the character.

Answer (score 1):

"советская гавань" in UTF-8, URL-encoded.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a [character encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding). That's [percent encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding). It's usually used to pass "special characters" through URL's.

Answer (score 0):

URLDecodes to советская гавань. Looks legit but I don't know the language.

Comment: That's Cyrillic, under each used in Russian.